# Excel Formula Help and Column Combining

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column B has: 0.0311274637822757
Column C has: =B6/0.0125
Column D has: =ROUND(C6,0)

In this example Column C = Column B is divided by .0125. Then answer C6 is rounded up to the nearest whole number.

2 Problems. I need to combine column C & D into 1 column. Also the rounding in this example does not round up properly. It rounds 2.5 to 2 and needs to be 3.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To combine C & D:
`=ROUND(B6/0.0125,0)`

Regarding the rounding, if you divide 0.0311274637822757 by 0.0125, you will see the answer is actually 2.490197102582056, so it is correctly rounding down, to 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly.